# Sometimes can't leave USB DFU bootloader

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I have an STM32F072 and am using the built-in bootloader (see [AN3156](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00264379-usb-dfu-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) to flash it via DFU over USB. Flashing works fine, but often it fails to leave the bootloader afterwards.

I am using `dfu-util` to flash (tried version 0.10 or latest from git):

```
dfu-util -a0 -D myfile.bin -s 0x08000000:leave
```

And when it fails to exit, I run this multiple times:

```
dfu-util -a0 -s 0x08000000:leave
```

I've went manually through the protocol steps for leaving DFU, and found it is always stuck in `dfuMANIFEST` (manifestation stage). However, **if I issue a bunch of DFU_GETSTATUS commands afterwards, it leaves DFU 100% of the time**. This should not be neccessary. It looks like just generating some USB traffic causes it to complete. This makes me think that maybe the interrupt setup is not right.

---

I also tried `pydfu.py`, which has the same problem. Example output of `dfu-util`:

```
# /opt/whizcart/easytest/dfu-util -s 0x08000000:leave -a0
dfu-util 0.10-dev
[...]
Opening DFU capable USB device...
Device ID 0483:df11
Device DFU version 011a
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Interface #0 ...
Determining device status...
DFU state(10) = dfuERROR, status(10) = Device's firmware is corrupt. It cannot return to run-time (non-DFU) operations
Clearing status
Determining device status...
DFU state(2) = dfuIDLE, status(0) = No error condition is present
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 2048
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash  "
DfuSe command mode
Submitting leave request...
Transitioning to dfuMANIFEST state
```

I think the "device's firmware is corrupt" is a red herring, I've confirmed that it is OK. This is just the response dfu-util gives on any error. I sometimes also get:

```
[...]
DFU state(7) = dfuMANIFEST, status(0) = No error condition is present
DFU mode device DFU version 011a
Device returned transfer size 2048
DfuSe interface name: "Internal Flash  "
DfuSe command mode
dfu-util: Failed to enter idle state on abort
```

The code I use to enter the bootloader is:

```c
void reboot_to_bootloader(){

    void (*jump_to_bootloader)(void);
    volatile uint32_t addr = 0x1FFFC800;

    //disable RCC, set to default
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    //disable systick
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    //reset USB;
    USB->BCDR=0;
    //disable irqs
    NVIC->ICER[0]=0xFFFFFFFF;
    //map system flash to 0x00000000
    SYSCFG->CFGR1 = 0x01;
    jump_to_bootloader = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *)(addr + 4 )));
    //set stack pointer
    __set_MSP(*(uint32_t *)addr);
    jump_to_bootloader();
}
```